# Asp.Net "plugin" architecture improvements

Tags: asp.net, reflection, plugins

At the moment we have an architecture where a dll is dropped into the bin folder which contains a certain class, the main application then looks for that class, using reflection, and runs a specific method which performs a function which isn't important here

Clearly reflection creates other issues, and has quite a large overhead...what other things could we do/use instead of reflection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Only on a small project where for us it fitted perfectly.  Obviously I can't speak for your solution but we were very happy with the development experience and overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

MEF as already stated is a good option - it's whole ethos is pluggable architecture.

The overhead of reflection is really only a problem if you do it multiple times.. if you cache the types you find then you won't have to go looking for them again.